# HTTP invoker remote won't work if client/Server has different package name?

Tags: java, remote-access, httpinvoker, remote-client

An error occurs while developing a client-side remote service. and i've found A package/class POJO name that does not exist in the new project (but still exists in the old project/server) from error Message . Is this cause a package name difference? If so, how can I remoteize this service?

**error message**

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not deserialize result from HTTP invoker remote service [http://---------/SERVICENAME.http]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: COM.OLD.CLASS.POJO
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.convertHttpInvokerAccessException(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:226)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2298.eaiConn(Unknown Source)
    ....
    at com.mois.app.idm.am.client.ApigSvcClient$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2b64bddf.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.lambda$doSubmit$3(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: COM.OLD.CLASS.POJO
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:144)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:76)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1986)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1850)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2160)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doReadRemoteInvocationResult(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:290)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.readRemoteInvocationResult(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:244)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:140)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:188)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:154)
    ... 16 more
```

**Remote Service**

```
@Configuration
public class service{
    
    @Bean
    public HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean CService() {
        HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean httpInvoker = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();
        httpInvoker.setServiceInterface(AInterface.class);
        httpInvoker.setServiceUrl("http://-----------/SERVICENAME.http"); 
        httpInvoker.afterPropertiesSet(); 
                
        return httpInvoker;
    }
    
}
```

**Interface and POJOS**

```
@Service

public Interface AInterface {

    public POJO method(...)


}




public class POJO implements Serializable {

    ...

}
```

your help would be much appreciated, thank you.